# When were "bump / IDC" connectors (2 row, 0.1" grid, mass-term ribbon cable) introduced? By whom?

Tags: connector

I am doing a timeline of connectors and I can't place these [these connectors](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=standard_rect_conn&o=bump_conn&fl=0000000000000000000000000000000000-1000-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C). [image] Who introduced them? (3M?) And when?

Comment: I was using them in 1976, they were fairly new at the time. I am guessing that they were developed in the early 1970s. I believe that 3M was the first.

Comment: No dates given, but 3M claims that they were the first for several technologies. See last page. https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/1425176O/3m-slimline-twin-axial-cable-assembly-sff-8654-for-sas-and-pcie-applications.pdf

Comment: "3M claims"... it says: "the latest in a long line of 3M innovations in electronics
cabling technology, including the first mass-termination interconnect system". That's a hint, but it may have been for some other connector. Thanks.

Comment: > I was using them in 1976 ... That's the best point in time I got so far. Thanks.

Comment: I am fairly certain that the pictured connector was the original IDC. There was still a lot of marketing hype in 1976, that is why I believe that it was invented shortly before that.

Comment: I thought the original mass-terminated ribbon cable connector was a board-in (direct to PCB) permanent connector: a transition connector (https://www.digikey.se/product-detail/en/cw-industries/CWR-142-26-0203/CPC26S-ND/1122546). Or maybe the DIP component carrier that fit into a 16-pin DIP socket. It came also as a mass terminated connector. (https://syntaur.com/images/1424-Lg.jpg) Remember those? Which came first? Thank you.

Comment: This is what I am working on: http://connectorbook.com/timeline.html

Comment: 3M is a *materials* company. Developing an insulation that could reliably be pierced and was still durable was a key to these cables. The DIP sockets, headers, and direct to PCB alternatives were the easy part and followed quickly.

Comment: Thank you very much.